# What does Steam require from a Greenlight submission?

Tags: steam, export

I'm an indie developer getting ready to submit my game to Steam Greenlight, but have hit a road block. I don't know what to submit.

I've been searching and I haven't found anything detailing whether I should submit the game's files and let Steam do the rest or an installer to install the resource files and the executable in a certain spot?

Do I need to make any Steam-specific optimizations/additions to my game before it can be submitted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Steam doesn't even allow you to send executables directly to them. What you need instead is a trailer, and at least four screenshots of your game.

In addition to those, you need a written description of your game and a square-shaped branding image.

You also need to have paid the Greenlight fee.

Take a look at the [Steam Greenlight FAQ](https://steamcommunity.com/greenlight/faq/), it was a great resource for me while I was getting prepared for my campaign. 
I also suggest that you take a look at a few submission pages.

Now, it's a different question whether you should provide a download link to a potential demo release to increase your chances of getting votes, but that cannot be answered very objectively.

Comment: Pay the greenlight fee, and it will allow you to submit your game.  It creates a button on your profile's main greenlight page that says "Submit your application".